# Syntax-highlight for tag jruby similar to that of ruby

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, syntax-highlighting

Questions tagged with [jruby](/questions/tagged/jruby) do not seem to have an associated ruby syntax highlighting applied, the way [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) questions have it:

- JRuby sample question: [How can I eval code in JRuby, in a new context every time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292761/how-can-i-eval-code-in-jruby-in-a-new-context-every-time)
- Ruby sample question: [How to capture a key press in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297753/how-to-capture-a-key-press-in-ruby)

From what I understand, the `J` in `JRuby` only stands for a Java *implementation*. Apart from that, it is actually the ruby language (see http://jruby.org/).